# Macro name expanded from another macro in makefile

Tags: macros, makefile

I have a makefile with the following format. First I define what my outputs are;

```
EXEFILES = myexe1.exe myexe2.exe
```

Then I define what the dependencies are for those outputs;

```
myexe1.exe : myobj1.obj
myexe2.exe : myobj2.obj
```

Then I have some macros that define extra dependencies for linking;

```
DEP_myexe1 = lib1.lib lib2.lib
DEP_myexe2 = lib3.lib lib4.lib
```

Then I have the target for transforming .obj to .exe;

```
$(EXEFILES):
    $(LINK) -OUT:"Exe\$@" -ADDOBJ:"Obj\$<" -IMPLIB:$($($(DEP_$*)):%=Lib\\%)
```

What I want to happen is (example for myexe1.exe)

```
DEP_$* -> DEP_myexe1
$(DEP_myexe1) -> lib1.lib lib2.lib
$(lib1.lib lib2.lib:%=Lib\\%) -> Lib\lib1.lib Lib\lib2.lib
```

Unfortunately this is not working. When I run `make --just-print`, the `-IMPLIB:` arguments are empty. However, if I run `$(warning DEP_$*)` I get

```
DEP_myexe1
```

And when I run `$(warning $(DEP_myexe1))` I get

```
lib1.lib lib2.lib
```

So for some reason, `make` does not like the combination of `$(DEP_$*)`. Perhaps it cannot resolve macro names dynamically like this. What can I do to get this to work? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does `$(warning DEP_$*)` give you `DEP_myexe1` as output exactly? Because given your makefile above it shouldn't.

`$*` is the stem of the target pattern that matched. In your case, because you have explicit target names, you have no patten match and so no stem and so `$*` is always empty.

Additionally, you are attempting a few too many expansions. You are expanding `$*` to get `myexe1` directly (assuming for the moment that variable works the way you intended). You then prefix that with `DEP_` and used `$(DEP_$*)` to get the `lib1.lib lib2.lib`. You then expand that result `$($(DEP_$*))` and then expand that (empty) result again (to do your substitution) `$($($(DEP_$*)):%=Lib\\%)`.

You want to either use `$(@:.exe=)` instead of `$*` in your rule body or use `%.exe` as your target and then use `$*` to get `myexe1`/`myexe2`.

You then want to drop two levels of expansion from `$($($(DEP_$*)):%=Lib\\%)` and use `$(DEP_$*:%=Lib\\%)` instead.

So (assuming you use the pattern rule) you end up with:

```
%.exe:
        $(LINK) -OUT:"Exe\$@" -ADDOBJ:"Obj\$<" -IMPLIB:$(DEP_$*:%=Lib\\%)
```

Comment: Ahaa, I didn't know @ could be used in a replace rule away from $ like that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And to answer your question, between the target and recipe for EXEFILES. It did give me myexe1, honest :-S

Comment: I didn't understand that first comment about `@` and I find the second comment hard to believe but <shrug>.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working without needing to resolve macros in the way described above. I modified the linking dependencies like this;

```
myexe1.exe : myobj1.obj lib1.lib lib2.lib
myexe2.exe : myobj2.obj lib3.lib lib4.lib
```

Then I need to filter these files by extension in the target recipe;

```
$(EXEFILES):
    $(LINK) -OUT:"$(EXE_PATH)\$@" -ADDOBJ:$(patsubst %, Obj\\%, $(filter %.obj, $^)) -IMPLIB:$(patsubst %, Lib\\%, $(filter %.lib, $^))
```

The `$(pathsubst ...)` is used to prepend the path that the relevant files are in.

In the case of myexe1.exe, the link command expands to;

```
slink -OUT:"Exe\myexe1.exe" -ADDOBJ: Obj\myexe1.obj -IMPLIB: Lib\lib1.lib Lib\lib2.lib
```

Out of interest's sake, I would still like to know if it is possible to resolve macro names like in the question.